# Circular view path, Spring Boot, Gradle and mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle

I´m trying to execute an app using spring boot but I got the following error message:"Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/test/index] again". I already see some similar post but I didn't have success.

Below you can see the error message:

```
Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/test/index] again
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories { 
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }

}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
}

}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
}
```

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
package com.hellomvc.test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setCache(false);
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    return resolver;
}

}
```

**AppInitializer**

```
package com.hellomvc.test.initializer;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "com.hellomvc.test.config";
private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/";

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new   DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
    return context;
}

}
```

**Controller**:

```
package com.hellomvc.test.controller;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.hello.spring.example.controller")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcome(@PathVariable("name") String name) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("index");
    model.addObject("name", name);

    return model;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {enter code here
    SpringApplication.run(HelloController.class, args);
}

}
```

Thanks for your help.
Edgardo

Comment: For starters use the framework, you are trying very hard to not use the framework. Your `AppInitializer` doesn't do anything in a Spring Boot application, it can be removed. The same goes for your `WebMvcConfig` as that is al done by Spring Boot. IN your build file remove the dependency on `spring-webmvc` as that is already provided by the starter you use. Tp configure the view resolver add an `application.properties` and include the `spring.view.suffix` and `spring.view.prefix` properties.

Comment: Hi @M. Deinum, I already removed both classes (AppInitializer and WebMvcConfig) and the dependency from the build file. also I added the application.properties that you mention but the result is the same, Which framework do you recomend? should I create xml files?

Comment: No don't use xml, use java based config and first understand Spring Boot and what it gives you. Work with it, not around/against it. The circular path error is due to some misconfiguration. When you enable debug logging you should be able to see what is going on.